# Limit of sequence of rationals in $A \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of rational numbers in $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. I think that I understand why this sequence will always converge (because $\mathbb{R}$ is an ordered set, so $\{x_n\}$ can be rearranged if necessary to obtain a monotonic sequence, which always converges).

But is it always true that $x = \lim_n\{x_n\} \in A$?

I'm looking at an example where $A = (0, 1]$, and $x \in A$, but I can't tell if it's because of the choice of $A$ or if it's a general result. I suspect that it's the latter, and that it may related to the denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$, but I can't formalize it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The sequence $(x_n)$ will certainly not converge in general, unless $A$ contains just one rational point. Suppose $A$ contains at least two rational points, $u$ and $v$. Then the sequence $(u,v,u,v,\ldots)$ doesn't converge. You seem to have your definitions confused. (Also, whatever it is that you are trying to ask, I suspect that it will require $A$ to be bounded.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless $A$ contains only a single number, which would be rather pathological, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ does not have to converge. One could take two different numbers $a$ and $b$ and alternate between them to get an oscillating sequence $(a,b,a,b,a,\dots)$ which will not converge.

---

Neither does the additional requirement that $\{x_n\}$ is monotonic make it converge: Let $A=\Bbb N$, then the sequence $(1,2,3,4,5,\dots)$ does not converge. To be certain that the sequence converges, you need it to be monotonic *and* $A$ needs to be bounded. That is: bounded monotonic sequences do converge.

---

For a general $A\subset \Bbb R$ and sequence $\{x_n\}$ with terms in $A$, it does not have to hold that $x=\lim_n \{x_n\}\in A$. For example, we could take $A=(0,1]$ and let $x_n=\frac 1n$ for each $n$, then $\lim_n\{x_n\}=0$ and $0\notin A$. The property that every converging sequence with terms in $A$ converges to a limit in $A$ holds if and only if $A$ is a *closed set*.

Comment: I would add for the benefit of the proposer that a re-arranged sequence is (usually) not the same sequence, and that it is often impossible to re-arrange a bounded sequence into  a monotone sequence.